# How do I set up Electrum Tor Wallet (for XVG) right?

Tags: software-installation, tor, ethereum

I followed a [step-by-step tutorial to set up Electrum (Tor)](https://github.com/vergecurrency/electrum-xvg-tor) for Ubuntu 16.04. After

```
sudo pip install pyasn1 pyasn1-modules pbkdf2 tlslite qrcode
```

I ignored the first orange notification,

> that the directory is not owned by current user… etc

but tried to upgrade pip version from 8.1.1 to 9.0.1 with the command:

```
pip install –upgrade pip
```

After upgrading, it showed still the 8.1.1 version. After a second try (same command), it said it s already up to date.

So I finished the tutorial and tried to run

```
cd /home/username/electrum-xvg-tor
./electrum-xvg
```

but instead of executing, it said:

```
bash: ./electrum-xvg: Keine Berechtigung (no authorization)
```

Any suggestions, what I missed? How can I get the wallet running?

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ apt-cache policy python-pip
python-pip:
  Installiert:           8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
  Installationskandidat: 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.1.1-2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

> `$ ls -l /home/username/electrum-xvg-tor/electrum-xvg`
>
> `-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 14345 Jan 14 16:19 /home/username/electrum-xvg-tor/electrum-xvg`

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Right, the main question was what I have to do to start the wallet.

Comment: The list actually shortened since yesterday (?), hope this is the right edit form, so you can find the error.

Comment: Did you run the last two commands from the linked instructions, `pyrcc4 icons.qrc -o gui/qt/icons_rc.py && sudo python setup.py install`? Did they succeed? What's the output of `ls -l /home/username/electrum-xvg-tor/electrum-xvg`?

Comment: Yes I ran all commands, and yes it succeed (there was no message or notification, it just took 1-2 secs and I had my next command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in the source code repository: the executable file appearing in the README document isn't flagged as executable (see [my bug report](https://github.com/vergecurrency/electrum-xvg-tor/issues/27)).

You can change its access mode to make it executable yourself:

```
chmod +x electrum-xvg
```

Then you can execute it as documented:

```
./electrum-xvg
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, it starts now. :) Next step will be to connect the wallet. It gave out a "Not connected" warning during start.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: Just opened a new question yesterday, if you re in please have a look :)